# Three.js GetWorldPosition() / localToWorld() position not correct?

Tags: three.js

I try to get worldposition of some child object using raycast, and then position a cube in exact position as my intersected object , but the placement is not same as what i expected , needed help, below is the code im using

```
  raycaster.setFromCamera(new THREE.Vector2(), camera);
  const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );
  if(intersects.length > 0){
    var object = intersects[0].object;
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 ), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );

    var pos = new THREE.Vector3();
    object.localToWorld( pos );
    cube.position.copy( pos );
    scene.add( cube );
```

when i add the cube into the scene the cube appear in other position , please let me know what am i missing here , thank you.

Edited
below is my screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Object3D.localToWorld()` converts the given vector to world space. Since you pass in the null vector, the result is not as expected. Do this instead:

```js
var pos = new THREE.Vector3();
pos.copy( object.position );
object.localToWorld( pos );
```

Or in a more readable fashion:

```js
var pos = new THREE.Vector3();
object.getWorldPosition( pos );
```

Comment: I tried your solution , but it still produce the same problem , btw , if i using getWorldPosition() i get 0,0,0 , even i try to update the matrix using parent.updateMatrixWorld(true);

Comment: `Object3D.getWorldPosition()` ensures to properly update the world matrix. Do you mind demonstrating the issue with a live example? https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/